# How to Use a Variable which is a URL and pass it to a href tag so it opens as a Hyperlink in HTML code

Tags: php, html

```
var= www.google.com
```

Now I want to pass this variable to an a `href` tag, how shall I do it?

I tried doing below but it didn't work. I need to pass it as variable since every time the url is going to be different.

```
<a href = " {{$var}} ">NoAbTerm</a>
```

Appreciate your any help.

Comment: you want with php or javscript ?

Comment: Where does your variable come from ? PhP ? `<input type="text" />` ?

Comment: `var= www.google.com` That's not valid PHP. (It isn't valid JS either).

Comment: `<a href = " {{$var}} ">NoAbTerm</a>` — What is that? Is it supposed to be part of a PHP string literal?

Answer (score -1):

If you want the variable as php, you could do this:

```
$whatevervariable = "http://www.google.com";

/* then, you can echo it out */

echo"
<a href='".$whatevervariable."'>google</a>
";
```

Comment: Did you put it in the <?php  ?> tag?